# ZendClient replacement with LaminasClient in Magento 2.4.6

Tags: laminas, magento2.4.6

In magento 2.4.5, I use some function below to connect with QBO sandbox ZendClient and it's working perfectly:

- setUri()
- setConfig(array())
- setHeaders()
- setRawData()
- request($method) ($method can be GET, POST,...)

In magento 2.4.6, ZendClient is replacement by LaminasClient. I have try function from new class LaminasClient:

- setUri() => setUri()
- setConfig(array()) => setOptions(array())
- setHeaders() => setHeaders()
- setRawData() => setRawBody()
- request($method) => send()

But the response have status code is 401. I have try debug into function send() and get $uri, $header to test in postman and postman return correctly information of sandbox QBO. I don't know why this happen. Can anyone give me some advices?
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have try replacement **ZendClient** with class **Laminas\Http\Client** and it working. This would help me compatible module with Magento version 2.4.6 and the old version 2.4.x can use it too.

Some change function:

- setUri() => setUri()
- setConfig(array()) => setOptions(array())
- setHeaders() => setHeaders()
- setRawData() => setRawBody()
- request($method) => send() (before use send(), you need set method with function setMethod($method) first.

Hope this answer could help someone.

Comment: Also note, in response, isSuccessful() changed to isSuccess() and getStatus() changed to getStatusCode(). Please refer classes located at vendor/laminas/laminas-http/src